# .NET WinForms language localization

Tags: .net, winforms, localization

I have a WinForm .NET software and am trying to get translated localization to work. For each form, I set `Localizable = True` and set `Language` from `Default` (which were defined in English) to `Italian (Italy)`. I then change all form strings from English to Italian.

I then set my PC's Region to Italy and language to Italian, but I do not see the Italian strings, just the default, English ones. I also tried `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("it-IT")` to force the EXE to be localized to it-IT, no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean, set the form strings? Are you hard coding the strings and they're still coming out in English? Have you checked your `.it-IT.resx` files?

Comment: be sure satellite assemblies built correctly and copied into bin folder

Comment: I've checked the it-IT.resx files and they are set to Italian strings. and the default resx has them in English. I assumed that when it detected the Italian region code, it would simply use the it-IT.resx resources.

Comment: you must also set Thread.CurrentThread.Culture to new CultureInfo("it-IT")

Comment: VahiD - a /bin/Release/it-IT folder exists with a single ProjectName.resources.dll that updates anytime I make a change to the it-IT.resx file.

Comment: after defining resx files, and build projects, some assemblies will be copied into bin folder something like this Project.resources.dll in a folder named "it" for example

Comment: You mean Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture? I did that too.

Comment: is your application single thread or multi-thread? maybe your form is not running in a thread which you set culture

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32430/discussion-between-vahid-and-mraviator)

Comment: Definitely single threaded. Is there a folder structure example on where the translated resx should go?

Comment: what is the neutral language of project?

Comment: Following this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385967.aspx) it's set to None.

Comment: It must set to none otherwise .Net assume that your main dll is in that language so does not load satellite assemblies. Trace your application where form is loaded, then check CurrentThread.Culture, is it still it-IT ?

Comment: You've been very helpful, thank you. Just one more question. If I localize every form and create a it-IT.resx for every form, will there just be one ProjectName.resources.dll or one for each form? I think there will just be one such file and not for each form, but wanted to verify.

Comment: Yes ther will be just one for each project, you can open that assembly with reflector and see what resources are inside it. good luck